# MS SQL which best data configuration for huge online datas?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a database on SQL SERVER, which has a mix of operational data and huge amount of storage data:

1. Nr 15 table for configuration infos;
2. Nr 3 tables with huge amount of data for every month:

   - Data of current month are updated every night (in batch processes)
   - Data of past months, for 3 years, are read but not updated anymore

The complexities are:

- Each month has 30M to 50M rows;
- Data of past months should stay online;
- Nightly processes recalculate whole month data, so t-log after every night grown huge (GBs);
- Primary key of data is like that: **month, keyvalue**;
- Many queries insist on both current and previous months, reading many months together;

  - Each keyvalue spans for average one year (6 to 24 month);
  - Most common queries read by keyvalues, filtering or grouping keyvalues on period ranges

A query example is sum of `amount` for a group of keys:

```sql
    select t.kevalue, sum(t.amount) as total_value
    from HUGE_TABLE_DATA t
    inner join KEYLIST k
    on k.kevalue = t.kevalue
    where t.month between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
```

**Which is the best configuration to store data, save time and keep backup/restore as light as possible?**

---

My possible solutions, up to now, are two, but both have drawbacks:

1. Create different filegroups for each month data, and a `Partition Scheme`. This way, I can also backup different partitions in different files: But:

   - I need Full Recovery mode, and t-log will be very huge;
   - For every full backup I still need to backup everything, including past months;
2. Create different database, one for read/write data and the other with readonly data. This way, I can have different backup politics for different database. But:

   - I need `views` and `union all` to keep together data for different months, and they perform worse than a query on single table. Query with joins are far more worse;
   - Working on two or more databases is always tricky, has limitations, can involve many `alias`, can have permission issue, and so on...

Comment: What are you using or think you need Partitioning for though?...what kind of queries / operations are you hoping to improve by using it? Example queries would be helpful.

Comment: On the first solution the both drawbacks are not true. Why do you think t-log will be very huge? It depends on the DB load but not on its structure. About backups read: [Partial Database Backups and Restores with Read-Only Filegroups](https://chad-franklin.com/2021/05/02/partial-database-backups-and-restores-with-read-only-filegroups/). I would create one filegroup for a year to decrease its count.

Comment: Each keyvalue spans for about one year. I work seekeing or grouping by keyvalues. Nightly processes do a lot and recalculate whole month data, so t-log after night is huge (GBs). I update topic text.

Comment: "*Most common queries read by keyvalues, filtering or grouping keyvalues on period ranges*" - Partitioning doesn't improve query performance for these kind of queries (including your example query). Partitioning isn't meant to be used as a performance tool, rather it's meant for improved data management (e.g. if you wanted to `TRUNCATE` whole partitions at one time). This is why I question your need for it. And if you don't need it, and you don't need granular backups, then you can probably switch your database to `Simple Recovery Model` to solve your other Post's questions.

Comment: I do need granular backup, cause I don't want to backup whole database each time. I wish to backup only mothly data and configuration data. I don't want to waist time on backup 35 month of data of past months

Comment: @Radioleao By granular backups, I mean Transaction Log backups for point in time recovery. In `Simple Recovery Model` you'd be able to still do Differential Backups which would only contain any changes to the data and not the "*35 month of data of past months*" if it hasn't changed.

Comment: It's a best practice to do a periodic full backup (i.e. one each month?). If I do as you say, and I avoid huge `FULL Backup` based on a differential back policy, I would do only differential backup for 3 years. Right?

Comment: @Radioleao Sorry I don't fully understand your question, could you please try wording it differently? If you switched to `Simple Recovery Model` then the amount of full backups will depend on how quickly you'd want to be able to restore. The less Differentials needed to restore (because you have a more recent Full backup), the quicker the overall restore time will take. But that's the tradeoff. If you don't care about a super fast restore time, you can take fewer Full backups. Your backup granularity will be based on how frequently you takd Differential backups too.

Comment: @Radioleao so for example, you could get away with a monthly Full backup with a daily Differential backup each day. You'd have about 30 Differential backup files, and they'd only contain what changed since the previous day, not any unchanged data.

Comment: Every **Full Backup** will keep also all 35 readonly months. If I want to keep saves of past months of configuration tables, I need full backups with waste o space. It would be better if there is a way to split filegroups backup. Moreover, 30 differential backup in a month will grown more than I want; I’m thinking about weekly full backups.

Comment: "*Every Full Backup will keep also all 35 readonly months.*" - Yes, that's why you would do them less frequently (at some point you'll need a Full backup regardless of what you do). "*30 differential backup in a month will grown more than I want*" - And what's it make a difference if you have larger Differential backup files? If you took more frequent Full backups, such as weekly like you mentioned, that growth of space will now be stored in the Full backup instead. Either way, it's the same amount of space.

Comment: @Radioleao Based on your situation, what you really should do is store the large read only historical data in a separate table. Then you can put that whole table on its own read-only filegroup. That would allow you take whatever backups you want (with "partial backups") of just the non-read-only filegroup(s) which is the much smaller data you have. It would also allow you to switch to `Simple Recovery Model` and no longer need to worry about Transaction Log backups, if you wanted. You're not using Partitioning for any of the features it's intended for, so I'd recommend getting rid of it.

Comment: Here's a link to the [docs on partial backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/partial-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Your situation sounds very fitting for it.

Comment: Only 20 rows inserted per second.  But massive selects ro repeatedly rollup the data seems to be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Each night, roll up the day's data into a Summary Table (perhaps a "materialized view").  This table (or tables) will be much smaller than the raw data that you seem to be summaging through now.  It sounds like a summary table will be a million times smaller than what you are working with now.  Hence the following will be a lot faster:

"Nightly processes do a lot and recalculate whole month data" -- No.  Instead augment the SUMs collected so far.

Then rewrite the Report queries to reach into a Summary Table to sum up the sums and sum up the counts and generate averages using avg(sum of sums / sum of counts), etc.

No partitioning.  No UNION ALL.  No lots-of-the-same table.  Probably no big log files.

Well, if you need to delete "old" data, partitioning may help in that task.  Partition by, say, month.